# Updating label with Timer

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, timer

I have a `label` that gets filled with two `strings`, very short after each other, so only the last `string` will be visible in the `.Text property` of the `label`.

I want to have a pause of 1.5 seconds between those `strings`, example:

```
string strMessage1 = "ONE";

string strMessage2 = "TWO";

Label.Text = strMessage1;
//Pause of 1.5 seconds
Label.Text = strMessage2;
```

Now I tried setting up a `timer`, the following way:

```
private void FillString()
{
     stringTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
     stringTimer.Interval = 1500;
     stringTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(OnStringTimerElapsed);

     Label.Text = strMessage1;
     stringTimer.Start();
}

private void OnStringTimerElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Label.Text = strMessage2;
}
```

But it only shows the first `string` in the `label` and doesn't do anything with the second. What should I do?

Comment: Do you ever call the `FillString` method? [edit] I see -- `FillString` sets it to `strMessage1` then never sets it to `strMessage2`?

Comment: Yes, this is not my complete source code.

Comment: The when the Time interval has elapsed(1500 milliseconds) it should go to the OnStringTimerElapsed method, and that should Label.Text to strMessage2.

Comment: did you try to refresh your form after updating the label?

Comment: aaah thanks! Forgot to use: Label.Invalidate(); :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After assigning the second string value, invalidate the label object.

```
Label1.Invalidate();
```